# How to convert one table to another table structure and compare data | Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, diff

I have two table with different structure, but the `TableA`  few columns not same as `TableB`.
Here we have to convert `TableA` into `TableB` structure and compare each data and flag missing rows from `TableB`. If its missed in `TableA` I need to ignore such records.

I don't want to use `Union all` and as I am performing bulk operation need to consider query performance. Please suggest with best way.

**TableA**

| NAME | GENDER | DEPNAME | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 | ID5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jacob | M | Math |  | OfficeID | PassPort | AppID | JobID |
| Maria | F | Science | LabID | OfficeID | PassPort | AppID |  |

**TableB**

| NAME | GENDER | DEPNAME | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jacob | M | Math | OfficeID |
| Jacob | M | Math | PassPort |
| Jacob | M | Math | AppID |
| Maria | F | Science | LabID |
| Maria | F | Science | OfficeID |
| Maria | F | Science | PassPort |

**Table A-B**

| Name | Gender | DepName | ID | MissingID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jacob | M | Math | OfficeID | No |
| Jacob | M | Math | PassPort | No |
| Jacob | M | Math | AppID | No |
| Jacob | M | Math | JobID | Yes |
| Maria | F | Science | LabID | No |
| Maria | F | Science | OfficeID | No |
| Maria | F | Science | PassPort | No |
| Maria | F | Science | AppID | Yes |

Comment: Do you know about [unpivot](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-unpivot/)?

Comment: @Abra, How we use unpivot for only ID column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to unpivot `A` and then use `LEFT JOIN` to bring in the values from `b`:

```
SELECT a.*,
       (CASE WHEN b.id IS NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as is_missing
FROM (SELECT a.name, a.gender, a.depname, i.n, i.id
      FROM TableA a CROSS JOIN LATERAL
           (SELECT 1 as n, id1 as id FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 as n, id2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 as n, id3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 as n, id4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 as n, id5 FROM DUAL
           ) i
      WHERE id IS NOT NULL
     ) a LEFT JOIN
     tableb b
     ON a.name = b.name AND a.gender = b.gender AND a.depname = b.depname AND a.id = b.id
ORDER BY a.name, a.gender, a.depname, a.n;
```

I prefer lateral joins for unpivoting.  In Oracle 11 you also have the option of unpivot.  However, the more general approach does use `union all` (although a faster method uses `union all` with a `cross join`).

Note that no aggregation is needed.  And that this returns the ids in the order they appear in `A`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ef893b0dcccbc2fb2878ce424f16f91d) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Conditional Aggregation along with unpivoted rows for all distinct ID values of the columns of the TableA such as

```
SELECT a.name AS "Name", a.gender AS "Gender", a.depname AS "Dept Name", a.id, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN a.id != b.id THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS "MissingID"
  FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT *
      FROM TableA a   
   UNPIVOT (id FOR col IN ( id1 AS 'id1',
                            id2 AS 'id2',
                            id3 AS 'id3',
                            id4 AS 'id4',
                            id5 AS 'id5' ))) a
   JOIN TableB b
    ON b.name = a.name
   AND b.gender = a.gender
   AND b.depname = a.depname  
 GROUP BY a.name, a.gender, a.depname, a.id
 ORDER BY a.name, "MissingID"
```

| Name | Gender | DepName | ID | MissingID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jacob | M | Math | OfficeID | No |
| Jacob | M | Math | PassPort | No |
| Jacob | M | Math | AppID | No |
| Jacob | M | Math | JobID | Yes |
| Maria | F | Science | PassPort | No |
| Maria | F | Science | OfficeID | No |
| Maria | F | Science | LabID | No |
| Maria | F | Science | AppID | Yes |

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e375bf36e1b61c987610901ce3642497)</kbd>